# Sort a dictionary, copy it by row, then sort again the remaining rows in other conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sorting

I'm kind of new to python. So I am creating a cpu scheduling SJF. Here I let the user to input the no. of processes, then let them enter AT and BT for each

```
number_of_process = inputNumber("Enter number of processes: ") # Prompt to user to input number of processes
print()

dictionary = dict() # Dictionary Object

for i in range(number_of_process):
    
    process_id = i + 1
    key = "P" + str(process_id) # Set Process ID as key of dictionary object.   
    
    ArrivalTime = inputNumber("Enter Arrival Time of process " + str(process_id) + ": ")
    BurstTime = inputNumber(f"Enter Burst Time for process {process_id}: ")
    print()

    dictionary[key] = [ArrivalTime, BurstTime]
```

I should should the dictionary first according to AT

```
#sorted by AT
dict_AT = (sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1][0], item[1][1])))
```

compute for the ff

```
ET = [] # Exit Time
TAT = [] # Turn Around Time
WT = [] # Waiting Time
```

then print the row. should look like this:
[image]

my problem is for the SECOND SORTATION, I have this in a for loop. i need to have a condition where i need to get the rows where the previous row ET > AT(the rows i need to get) then SORT them according to the shortest BT.

[image]

Here instead of P4 P1 P2 P3 P5, the order needs to be P4 P1 P3 P5 P2
[image]

Since I am using a for loop, I am thinking of copying it by row to another dict. So the unaffected row of condition would be retained then sort again the original dict then copy again until all the rows are sorted. But i do not know how to do it. Or is there a better way?

Comment: As a rule of thumb in python: if you feel the need to call `sorted` on a dictionary, then you probably shouldn't have been using a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: @Stef noted! sorry I'm really just new in using python. can you recommended the better way of doing it? it will be much appreciated

Comment: It probably doesn't matter too much in your case. Note that `dict_AT`, despite its name, is not a dictionary, but a list (because `sorted` returns a list). So, the fact that `dictionary` is a dict is completely irrelevant. It might as well be a list. But that doesn't matter too much. If you find yourself going back and forth between `sorted` and `dict` then there's probably something wrong, but if it's just once like that it probably doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Note that `dict_AT` is a list of pairs of the form `(key, [arrivaltime, bursttime])` (because that's what's generated by `dictionary.items()` after storing `key: [arrivaltime, bursttime]` in the dict). Wouldn't you prefer instead a list of triples of the form `(key, arrivaltime, bursttime)`?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I'll go with your suggestion of list of triples.